# Whi is Spring OAuth2RestOperations HTTP client throwing ResourceAccessException instead of giving me back an HTTP response code?

Tags: spring, rest

I am trying to reverse engineer a working pice of software, to come up with a raw HTTP request, so I can fire it with Postman or other HTTp client.

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperations;

private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

@Autowired
public void setRestTemplate(OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}

private QuoteWorkflowResponse saveQuote(IQuoteRequest request) {
    RequestEntity<IQuoteRequest> requestEntity = RequestEntity.post(getPathToPurchaseUrl(request))
            .body(request);
    ResponseEntity<QuoteWorkflowResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, QuoteWorkflowResponse.class);
    if (responseEntity.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
        handleError(responseEntity);
    }
    return responseEntity.getBody();
}
```

This is somehow using Barrer Token, I fetched the token using the debugger and tested it in postman and it works.

My question here is, why restTemplate.exchange is throwing a ResourceAccessException ? what does that means ? and how can I fix it ?

Exception this is throwing:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://somehost/aabb/sales/quote": stream is closed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: stream is closed
```

Comment: What is the `message` of ResourceAccessException? Have you tried to get `RestTemplate` debug logs to doublecheck if URL is correct? Mainly I get `ResourceAccessException` in case of service unavailable but need more context.

Comment: Hi @MrFroll thanks for your answer, I will try RestTemplate debug.

yes the URL is correct.

Comment: You can start with logging. If you are using spring boot you can use `logging.level.org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate=DEBUG` to see url, headers etc.

Comment: awesome, thanks @MrFroll

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MrFoll, I have added this to my applicaion.yml

```
logging:
level:
    org:
      springframework:
                    web:
                      client:
                        RestTemplate: "DEBUG"
```

and fixed the issue.